# How to use `foreach` and `%dopar%` with an `R6` class in R?

Tags: r, parallel-processing, doparallel, parallel-foreach, r6

I ran into an issue trying to use `%dopar%` and `foreach()` together with an `R6` class. Searching around, I could only find two resources related to this, an unanswered [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49435632/5252007) and an open [GitHub issue](https://github.com/r-lib/R6/issues/141#issuecomment-421488625) on the `R6` repository.

In one comment (i.e., GitHub issue) an workaround is suggested by reassigning the `parent_env` of the class as `SomeClass$parent_env <- environment()`. I would like to understand what exactly does `environment()` refer to when this expression (i.e., `SomeClass$parent_env <- environment()`) is called within the `%dopar%` of `foreach`?

Here is a minimal reproducible example:

```r
Work <- R6::R6Class("Work",

    public = list(
        values = NULL,


        initialize = function() {
            self$values <- "some values"
        }
    )
)
```

Now, the following `Task` class uses the `Work` class in the constructor.

```r
Task <- R6::R6Class("Task",
    private = list(
        ..work = NULL
    ),


    public = list(
        initialize = function(time) {
            private$..work <- Work$new()
            Sys.sleep(time)
        }
    ),


    active = list(
        work = function() {
            return(private$..work)
        }
    )
)
```

In the `Factory` class, the `Task` class is created and the `foreach` is implemented in `..m.thread()`.

```r
Factory<- R6::R6Class("Factory",

    private = list(
        ..warehouse = list(),
        ..amount = NULL,
        ..parallel = NULL,


        ..m.thread = function(object, ...) {
            cluster <- parallel::makeCluster(parallel::detectCores() -  1)
            doParallel::registerDoParallel(cluster)

            private$..warehouse <- foreach::foreach(1:private$..amount, .export = c("Work")) %dopar% {
                # What exactly does `environment()` encapsulate in this context?
                object$parent_env <- environment()
                object$new(...) 
            }

            parallel::stopCluster(cluster)
        },


        ..s.thread = function(object, ...) {
            for (i in 1:private$..amount) {
               private$..warehouse[[i]] <- object$new(...)
            }
        },


        ..run = function(object, ...) {
            if(private$..parallel) {
                private$..m.thread(object, ...)
            } else {
                private$..s.thread(object, ...)
            }
        }
    ),


    public = list(
        initialize = function(object, ..., amount = 10, parallel = FALSE) {
            private$..amount = amount
            private$..parallel = parallel

            private$..run(object, ...)
        }
    ),


    active = list(
        warehouse = function() {
            return(private$..warehouse)
        }
    )
)
```

Then, it is called as:

```r
library(foreach)

x = Factory$new(Task, time = 2, amount = 10, parallel = TRUE)
```

Without the following line `object$parent_env <- environment()`, it throws an error (i.e., as mentioned in the other two links): `Error in { : task 1 failed - "object 'Work' not found"`.

I would like to know, (1) what are some potential pitfalls when assigning the `parent_env` inside `foreach` and (2) why does it work in the first place?

---

**Update 1:**

- I returned `environment()` from within `foreach()`, such that `private$..warehouse` captures those environments
- using `rlang::env_print()` in a debug session (i.e., the `browser()` statement was placed right after `foreach` has ended execution) here is what they consist of:

```r
Browse[1]> env_print(private$..warehouse[[1]])

# <environment: 000000001A8332F0>
# parent: <environment: global>
# bindings:
#  * Work: <S3: R6ClassGenerator>
#  * ...: <...>

Browse[1]> env_print(environment())

# <environment: 000000001AC0F890>
# parent: <environment: 000000001AC20AF0>
# bindings:
#  * private: <env>
#  * cluster: <S3: SOCKcluster>
#  * ...: <...>

Browse[1]> env_print(parent.env(environment()))

# <environment: 000000001AC20AF0>
# parent: <environment: global>
# bindings:
#  * private: <env>
#  * self: <S3: Factory>

Browse[1]> env_print(parent.env(parent.env(environment())))

# <environment: global>
# parent: <environment: package:rlang>
# bindings:
#  * Work: <S3: R6ClassGenerator>
#  * .Random.seed: <int>
#  * Factory: <S3: R6ClassGenerator>
#  * Task: <S3: R6ClassGenerator>
```

Comment: I've have bad luck trying to get objects with environments to be usable across nodes of a `parallel` clusters. R6 objects are [inherently environments](https://r6.r-lib.org/articles/Introduction.html), which are often used to accomplish *pass-by-reference* semantics (instead of R's default *pass-by-value*). In order to do that, the `environment` is modified in-place. Unfortunately, this env is not shared across cluster nodes, so even if an `environment` can be transferred to other nodes, often the premise of the object can be lost. (I don't know that the env can be transferred, btw.)

Comment: Reading that github issue, it is entirely possible I'm missing something ...

Comment: I thought the same until I read the GitHub issue! Now I think it is possible, at least the `object$parent_env <- environment()` makes it possible. Still, I don't get the reason behind...

Comment: Reasoning about it, I expected that if I include `self` in the `.export` this would also work, but it didn't: `object$parent_env <- parent.env(self$.__enclos_env__)`.

Comment: Could you please make your example more minimal?

Comment: Hi @F.Privé, sure, [here is a GitHub Gist containing a more minimal example](https://gist.github.com/mihaiconstantin/df755017643ff08d8ad32d51db42cf59). Does it help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disclaimer: a lot of what I say here are educated guesses and inferences based on what I know,
I can't guarantee everything is 100% correct.

I think there can be many pitfalls,
and which one applies really depends on what you do.
I think your second question is more important,
because if you understand that,
you'll be able to evaluate some of the pitfalls by yourself.

The topic is rather complex,
but you can probably start by reading about [R's lexical scoping](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functions.html#lexical-scoping).
In essence, R has a sort of hierarchy of environments,
and when R code is executed,
variables whose values are not found in the current environment
(which is what `environment()` returns)
are sought in the *parent* environments
(not to be confused with the caller environments).

Based on the GitHub issue you linked,
`R6` generators save a "reference" to their parent environments,
and they expect that everything their classes may need can be found in said parent or somewhere along the environment hierarchy,
starting at that parent and going "up".

The reason the workaround you're using works is because you're replacing the generator's parent environment with the one in the current `foreach` call inside the parallel worker
(which may be a different R process, not necessarily a different thread),
and, given your `.export` specification probably exports necessary values,
R's lexical scoping can then search for missing values starting from the `foreach` call in the separate thread/process.

For the specific example you linked,
I found that a simpler way to make it work
(at least on my Linux machine)
is to do the following:

```
library(doParallel)

cluster <- parallel::makeCluster(parallel::detectCores() -  1)
doParallel::registerDoParallel(cluster)
parallel::clusterExport(cluster, setdiff(ls(), "cluster"))

x = Factory$new(Task, time = 1, amount = 3)
```

**but** leaving the `..m.thread` function as:

```
..m.thread = function(object, amount, ...) {
    private$..warehouse <- foreach::foreach(1:amount) %dopar% {
        object$new(...) 
    }
}
```

(and manually call `stopCluster` when done).

The `clusterExport` call should have semantics similar to*:
take everything from the main R process' global environment except `cluster`,
and make it available in each parallel worker's global environment.
That way, any code inside the `foreach` call can use the generators when lexical scoping reaches their respective global environments.
`foreach` can be clever and exports some variables automatically
(as shown in the GitHub issue),
but it has limitations,
and the hierarchy used during lexical scoping can get very messy.

*I say "similar to" because I don't know what exactly R does to distinguish (global) environments if forks are used,
but since that export is needed,
I assume they are indeed independent of each other.

PS: I'd use a call to `on.exit(parallel::stopCluster(cluster))` if you create workers inside a function call,
that way you avoid leaving processes around until they are somehow stopped if an error occurs.

Comment: Hi @Alexis, thank you for such an elaborate answer and the resource on lexical scoping. It really helps me understand better what's going on and also how to use the search path to my advantage. P.S. The `on.exit` saves a lot of warnings for cluster-related connections... I will go ahead and mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: @Mihai no problem. Another advice: if you can put all your generators in your own R package, you can then tell `foreach` to load that package in each worker, and it'd probably save you some problems. You'd have to stop passing the generators directly to it, but you could pass a generator name and use `object <- get(...` or something similar inside the `foreach` call.

Comment: This seems like a very elegant solution! Indeed, all the generators live in the same package namespace and the sole purpose of the factory is to create objects from them. Thanks, I've learn a few very valuable things from you!