# How to use imported names from box modules inside parallel code?

Tags: r, rparallel, r-box

Here is a minimal example showing the issue:

#### `mod.r`:

```
#' @export
run_sqrt <- function (x) {
  sqrt(x)
}
```

#### `mwe.r`

```
box::use(
  ./mod[...],
  parallel,
  dp = doParallel,
  foreach[foreach, `%dopar%`],
)

cl <- parallel$makeCluster(2L)
dp$registerDoParallel(cl)

foreach(i = 1 : 5) %dopar% {
  run_sqrt(i)
}

parallel$stopCluster(cl)
```

This raises the error

> Error in { : task 1 failed - "could not find function "run_sqrt""

I found this

```
parallel::clusterExport(cluster, setdiff(ls(), "cluster"))
```

in [How to use `foreach` and `%dopar%` with an `R6` class in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57349958/how-to-use-foreach-and-dopar-with-an-r6-class-in-r)

But it didn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you found this is a limitation of the ‘parallel’ package. It only knows about names defined in the *current* environment.

There are several solutions for this. The following list is roughly in order of  (my personal) preference, from most preferred to least preferred.

1. Use explicitly qualified module access instead of attaching. So:

   1. Change `./mod[...]` to `./mod` inside `box::use()`
   2. Fully qualify the name inside `foreach`:

      ```
      foreach(i = 1 : 5) %dopar% {
        mod$run_sqrt(i)
      }
      ```

   Due to how `parallel` searches names, this will *only* work if the above code is executed in the global environment.
2. Import `./mod` *inside* the `foreach` body instead of at the beginning of your script. However, note that there is currently an [open bug](https://github.com/klmr/box/issues/312) regarding this solution.
3. Use `parallel::clusterExport`; this solution *works* if the correct names are provided, in this case `run_sqrt`. To make the minimal example work, add the following line before the `foreach` call:

   ```r
   parallel$clusterExport(cl, "run_sqrt", envir = environment())
   ```

   The reason why your version didn’t work is because `ls()` won’t list `run_sqrt`,  since the name is *attached*, it does not exist in the local scope. The same issue would exist with attached packages instead of modules. Furthermore, for reasons I do not understand, `clusterExport` by default searches names in the *global* environment only, you need to explicitly provide the *current* environment, via `envir = environment()`.

Comment: in original context, shiny App, answer does not work.  https://github.com/fernandoroa/boxandparallel

Comment: @Ferroao Indeed, apologies. Please see the correction. — That’s why it’s important to provide a *minimal* working example, so that I don’t guess which parts are relevant and which are not.

Comment: thanks it worked. In my context solution 3 was the best